# React & Objects - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to retrieve a list of objects (motors) from a django database and store it in the state of my MachineTemplate component.

Here's the component

```
export default class MachineTemplate extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
                this.state = {
            myName: this.props.match.params.id,
            motors: {},
            error: "None",
            loaded: false
        }
        
        this.getMachineDetails = this.getMachineDetails.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getMachineDetails();
    }

    getMachineDetails = () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
            name: this.state.myName,
            }),
        };

        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-motors", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                this.setState({ motors: response.data });
            } else {
                this.setState({ error: "Motors not found." });
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
        this.setState({loaded: true});
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loaded) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
                    <h3>{this.state.error}</h3>
                    {this.state.motors.map(motor => {
                        return <Button key = {motor.number}>{motor.number}</Button>
                    })}
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>Awaiting machine details...</h1>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the error I get
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

I can confirm the fetch is properly returning the list of motor objects I need, which are formatted like this in the response:
`0: {number: 0, enabled: true, item: "EMPTY", machine: 48}`

I was able to get this exact setup to work fine with a simple list of names in a different component, so any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @SpencerBrereton welcome! when using `fetch` you need to extract your data first with `response.json()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning an empty object to this.state.motors in the constructor. That's why you're getting the error. Should be an empty array.

Comment: that's right that should be an empty array the initial state, though an object is not `undefined` like the error points out

Comment: Yea, you're right. Though I think they should be getting another error that this.state.motors.map is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` is *asynchronous*. This means that you can't rely on it finishing its execution before the next statement:

```
fetch(/**/);
// ...
this.setState({loaded: true}) // fetch() might not finish executing when this statement is executed
```

So you have to make sure that you set your `loaded` state variable at the correct place. Looking at your code, something like this should work:

```
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-motors", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            this.setState({
                motors: response.json(), // As suggested by @buzatto
                loaded: true
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({ error: "Motors not found." });
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

---

### Fetching on every prop change

Consider adding [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to re-fetch and re-render your component with fresh data on props change:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.match.params.id !== prevProps.props.match.params.id) {
    this.setState({loaded: false}) 
    this.getMachineDetails();
  }
}
```

Also have a look at [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook that can simplify your code, merging the functionality of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` in *function* components:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setState({loaded: false}) 
  getMachineDetails();
}, [props.match.params.id]); // Only re-fetch if props.match.params.id changes
```

Comment: That's a problem I didn't even see until Don helped me clear up the main error. I set loaded=true where you recommended, but it looks like the component isn't re-rendering. Any clue how I can force it to update?